# Pandas Dataframe Drop Lines by Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have created some data:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Time': ['01.10.2019, 09:56:52', '01.10.2019, 09:57:15', '02.10.2019 09:57:23', '02.10.2019 10:02:58', '02.10.2019 13:11:58', '02.10.2019 13:22:55']
     ,'Action': ['Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed']
     ,'Name': ['CTO', 'CTO', 'CFO', 'CFO', 'CFO' , 'CFO']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    Time                    Action  Name
0   01.10.2019, 09:56:52    Opened  CTO
1   01.10.2019, 09:57:15    Closed  CTO
2   02.10.2019, 09:57:23    Opened  CFO
3   02.10.2019, 10:02:58    Closed  CFO
4   02.10.2019, 13:11:58    Opened  CFO
5   02.10.2019, 13:22:55    Closed  CFO
```

Now i want to drop the lines with the condition when the time < 5 minutes and if there are multiple lines with the same name it should drop the lines between the first "opened" action and the last "closed", so it will be everytime first opened as action and then closed if there is the same name. I tried with

```
mask = df.drop(df[pd.to_datetime(df["Time"]).diff().dt.seconds.gt(300)].index)
```

but that shows me only the first three lines. How could i do that?

my output should be like this then:

```
    Time                    Action  Name
0   02.10.2019, 09:57:23    Opened  CFO
1   02.10.2019, 13:22:55    Closed  CFO
```

because the first two are under 5 minutes and the third and fourth line are the same name as these before. But if the date is one day after it should be like this:

```
    Time                    Action  Name
2   02.10.2019, 09:57:23    Opened  CFO
3   02.10.2019, 10:02:58    Closed  CFO
4   03.10.2019, 13:11:58    Opened  CFO
5   03.10.2019, 13:22:55    Closed  CFO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the cleanest way in the world, but it gets the job done:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'Time': ['01.10.2019, 09:56:52', '01.10.2019, 09:57:15', '02.10.2019 09:57:23', '02.10.2019 10:02:58',
              '02.10.2019 13:11:58', '02.10.2019 13:22:55', '03.10.2019 14:20:44', '03.10.2019 14:30:44']
    , 'Action': ['Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed']
    , 'Name': ['CTO', 'CTO', 'CFO', 'CFO', 'CFO', 'CFO', 'CFO', 'CFO']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df.insert(1, 'Date', df['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.date()))

out = pd.DataFrame()
for name, group in df.groupby(['Name', 'Date']):
    first_open_idx = group[group['Action'] == 'Opened']['Time'].first_valid_index()
    last_close_idx = group[group['Action'] == 'Closed']['Time'].last_valid_index()

    if first_open_idx is not None and last_close_idx is not None:
        time_diff = group.loc[last_close_idx]['Time'] - group.loc[first_open_idx]['Time']
        if time_diff.seconds > 300:
            out = out.append(group[group.index.isin([first_open_idx, last_close_idx])])

print(out)
```

Comment: Thats quite good but how can i keep the data if the date will be changed to the third of october? because i tried it with your solution but it shows me this as print-out:                  
(2 2019-02-10 09:57:23  Opened  CFO)
(5 2019-03-10 13:22:55  Closed  CFO)

Comment: So you are saying you want to group both by name and by date?

Comment: Added groupby date, and also error handling in case there is missing open/close actions in the group. Also added two more rows to the original dataset, as an example